# MySql query double WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I currently have a query that checks whether a certain word is found in the array values.

```
$imploded = implode("','",$company_array); 
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key='company' 
          AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded."')";
```

The `$company_array` contains different values.

I want to add another WHERE clause but don't know how.
It should check on the users role:

```
SELECT*
FROM $wpdb->usermeta
WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
AND meta_value = 'subscriber'
```

Maybe some sort of join queries? I have no clue.

==== Sample data and expected output ====
This is my current query

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key='company' 
          AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded."')";
```

I want to add the following query

```
SELECT*
FROM $wpdb->usermeta
WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
AND meta_value = 'subscriber'
```

The first query loads a list of users that work for a certain company.
The problem is................

Crap. I just realised something while writing this.
The problem was that the administrator is also listed in the list of users. I wanted him out of the results.
The users are listed based upon their value in the `company` field. But if that is empty the admin isn't listed anywhere.

Comment: OR the two WHERE's together.

Comment: I've seen this but I assumed that `OR` checks if one or the other is true

Comment: Isn't that what you want? (You can't have both meta_key='company' and meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' at the same time.) Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I want them both true to continue. So Company should be in the array and the capabilities of the user that works for that company should have the suscriber role.

Comment: Either do a self join, or add an EXISTS to the WHERE clause. (Some sample data and expected result would help understanding...)

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause needs to be

```
WHERE (meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded."'))
   OR (meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value = 'subscriber')
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE (meta_key='company' 
          AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded."')) or (meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' and meta_value = 'subscriber')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you required below. Note the `()` with `OR` for your both where clauses.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE ( meta_key='company' AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded."')") 
          OR (meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value = 'subscriber');
```